# Django admin: Can I create a form for admin interface at runtime?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I want to display different forms in change_form depending on some model field's values.

For example (imagine we have a realty agency):

if `item.type == 'sale'`, I want to display 'price' field

if `item.type == 'rent'`, I want to display 'price_per_month', 'price_per_month' etc - but not price

ps: example is not perfect - because its problem can be solved via database structure - but my question is about *interface*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `ModelAdmin` method [`get_form`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.4/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L431) which takes the request and the object (watch out, it will be `None` when you're adding a new instance) and returns the form *class*.

The usual warning about overriding undocumented methods applies, be careful when upgrading as Django's [api stability promise](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/api-stability/) does not apply.

Comment: Sounds like a plan;) By the way, neithere used a method like this in eav-django (https://bitbucket.org/neithere/eav-django) - actualy I need to insert fields defined by users, and I want them to look 'native'. So, thanks :)